# Contract tests for two applications(not webservices) communicating by json file

Tags: testing, pact, spring-cloud-contract

I want to test communication between two applications(not webservices). One is generating json file as an output, second one is consuming this file. I would like to test if structure of this file is compatible with both applications. This file is stored in Azure. I was thinking about contract testing because they are faster then end-2-end tests, but in Pact's and Spring Cloud Contract's documantations I read that it is for REST communication tests. Could you help me find proper and fast way to test it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly the communication looks like? is it over HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pact Message and treat the document as the message, even though it doesn't go via a queue. If you go to https://docs.pact.io and put "JVM message" in the search box, you'll be able to find the docs for the various JVM technology options.